# How can I find my favorite wine?

Tags: wine

How do I find my favorite wine?  Obviously if I go drinking every bottle I can get my hands on I'd find one but I can't.  Also, I already know the general feel of the wine I'd like; i.e. dry, sweet, etc.  My question is, what are the things I should think about when trying to find my favorite wine?

Comment: I'm not sure about your assumption that there is such a thing as your 'favorite wine'.  (a) What wine I drink depends very much on what I will be eating with it. (b) Variety is a good thing.

Comment: I don't agree about (a) and (b).  However, what you wrote made me thing and you may be right.  It might not exist.

Comment: Whenever you get an opportunity to drink a certain type of wine, write down your opinions about it, what did you eat with it etc. It can help you decide which ones you like more and in which situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to be able to find the wine that best matches your tastes. it took me several months to sample different types of different regions. I am Italian, and here we assure you that there are many varieties of wines. I did courses, I just chose what I liked best. in my case my favorite wine is Amarone! we are not made equal, then a wine that you can enjoy, for others maybe not enthuse. I apologize for the translation from Italian to English, they are not very good! I hope to been helpful.

Answer (score 4):

1) Take a wine-tasting course. You will learn how different foods affect the flavour of wines. It really does make a difference (you will be astonished). You will also (hopefully) learn how to analyse wines (without being pretentious) and make useful notes.

2) Travel. Travel as much as you can and drink the local wines. If you find something that you really like and can afford to buy some, do so. You will never find your "favourite wine" by working your way systematically through your local wine shop.

3) Remember that wines change. One of the best wines that I ever tasted was a certain 1996 Amarone (Recioto della Valpolicella), and I was fortunate enough to be able to buy a case of it. However, once it was gone, it was gone. Later vintages (from the same producer) were not nearly as good.

4) Time passes. The wines that you love will be associated with treasured memories and inevitably belong to the past. You can never step into the same river twice. Such is the beauty of wine (and life).

Answer (score 2):

For me, the most important thing to select the wine I like/dislike is **grape variety**. You'll have to do some research and try some different grapes in order to know what you like and dislike.

**Country and region** can also have an influence. You'll also need to do some research for this.
For myself, I don't really like Bordeaux and Italian wines.

So you'll have som tasting to do. Try to write down what you liked and what you didn't like and it'll become clear what you're favourite style might be.